# URL for Uploading a document to a library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library

What is the URL for uploading a document to a library?
I have a document library whereby users can view and upload documents of several different content types.

I have also created a list that that has a link for all the views I created.  There is a column that stores the URL for uploading a document to the document library.
The reason to add this url being situations when the users stumble on the fact they need to click on `Upload Documment`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When upload form is open, right click on it and then click properties. You will get the URL in properties window.

Comment: I didn't have "Properties" for this.

I did have "View Frame Source" which gave me information that I could deduce the link from.

Answer (score 4):

You can create the url dynamically by using the following:
`http://sitecollectionurl/_layouts/Upload.aspx?List={document library id}`

In order to get the document library id, navigate to the `Library Settings` page. You will find the ID in the address bar as shown below:

[image]

You will have to decode the id using [this link](http://www.url-encode-decode.com/) and then use the plain id in the url mentioned above.

Comment: I get the result: "Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site. We can’t connect to the server at www.sitecollectionurl.com.' :/